# Bottom-left screen positioning CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the Card as i call it attached to the screen so when it is resized, the card will go along with it.

Css code:

```
    #wrapper {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1920px;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
#introduction-container {
    position: relative;
}
#introduction-textposition {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 10%; 
}
#introduction-paragraph {
    width: 500px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: rgba(18, 18, 18, 0.7);
    padding: 40px 25px;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

html code

```
 <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="introduction-container">
        <div id="introduction-textposition">
      <div id="introduction-paragraph">
        <h3>RTX 2080Ti Available Now!</h3>
        <h1>RAY-TRACE</h1>
        <p><span style="color: rgb(118, 185, 0);">NVIDIA RTX</span> is the most advanced platform for ray tracing and AI technologies that are revolutionizing the ways we play and create</p>
        <div>
            <a href="#" class="introduction-button hover-color">SHOP NOW!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

ps: the introduction-textposition percentaged is me playing around with it, wont work tho.
problem is, when i used the relative position on #introduction-container it the properties wont show here;
[html image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8Hfg.jpg)

What it should look like: [illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etdHK.jpg)

Comment: Do you want it to take the full screen like the attached image?

Comment: okay, so i have updated the thread with the new "what it should look like" i hope that helps @ruleboy21

Ps: im only using NVIDIA as this is only for school project. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (Open it in "full page" mode)

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
}
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1920px;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
#introduction-paragraph {
    width: 400px;
    background-color: rgba(18, 18, 18, 0.7);
    padding: 40px 25px;
    margin-top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10%;
    left: 10%; 
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="introduction-paragraph">
        <h3>RTX 2080Ti Available Now!</h3>
        <h1>RAY-TRACE</h1>
        <p><span style="color: rgb(118, 185, 0);">NVIDIA RTX</span> is the most advanced platform for ray tracing and AI technologies that are revolutionizing the ways we play and create</p>
        <div>
            <a href="#" class="introduction-button hover-color">SHOP NOW!</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! it works! thank you very much, although i just made a little adjustment on the width from 400px to 500px, now it works perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Let me help my bro, maybe my css can help you

```css
#wrapper{
background-image: linear-gradient(#1391ff,#0145ff);
    width: 200px;
    height: 160px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 16px;
    padding: 120px 50px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #000000ab;
}
```

```html
 <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="introduction-container">
        <div id="introduction-textposition">
      <div id="introduction-paragraph">
        <h3>RTX 2080Ti Available Now!</h3>
        <h1>RAY-TRACE</h1>
        <p><span style="color: rgb(118, 185, 0);">NVIDIA RTX</span> is the most advanced platform for ray tracing and AI technologies that are revolutionizing the ways we play and create</p>
        <div>
            <a href="#" class="introduction-button hover-color">SHOP NOW!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort! But this has already been answered thank you, again!